# How does a lock work for two inserts in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, isolation-level

Let's say isolation level is Repeatable Read as it's really is as default for MySQL.

I have two inserts (no checking, no unique columns).

a) Let's say these two inserts happen at the same moment. What will happen? Will it first run the first insert and the second or both of them in different MySQL's threads?

b) Let's say I have insert statement and column called `vehicle_id` as unique, but before that, I check if it exists or not. If it doesn't exist, go on and insert. Let's say two threads in my code both come at the same moment. So they will both go into `if` statement since they happened at the same moment.

Now, they both have to do insert with the same `vehicle_id`. How does MySQL handle this? If it's asynchronous or something, maybe both inserts might happen so quickly that they will both get inserted even though `vehicle_id` was the same as unique field. If it's not asynchronous or something, one will get inserted first, second one waits. When one is done, second one goes and tries to insert, but it won't insert because of unique `vehicle_id` restriction. How does this situation work?

I am asking because locks in repeatable read for `INSERT` lose their essence. I know how it's going to work for `Updating/Selecting.`

Comment: First come First Served! First attempt will lock out the other until it is completed, second attempt will fail with constraint error

Comment: So, when inserting two rows in the same table, another one won't get inserted until the first one?

Comment: how first one is gonna lock out the second came one if the first one doesn't know what to place the lock on unless single insert places the lock on the whole table so that no one can write unless the first one finishes the inserting

Comment: The database is clever! It locks what is required store a row, to ensure consistency. Remember this is a proper DBMS not Access

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the situation is:

a) the threads are assigned for each connection.  If both updates are received on the same connection then they will be executed in the same thread, one after the other according to the order in whcih they are received.  If they're in different threads then it will be down to whichever thread is scheduled first and that's likely to be OS determined and non-deterministic from your point of view.

b) if a column is defined as UNIQUE at the server, then you cannot insert a second row with the same value so the second insert must fail.

Trying to use a conflicting index in the way you described appears to be an application logic problem, not a MySQL problem. Whatever entity is responsible for your unique ID's (which is your application in this case) it needs to ensure that they are unique.  One approach is to implement an Application Lock using MySQL which allows applications running in isolation from each other to share a lock at the server.  Check in the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html) for how to use this.  It's usual use is intended to be application level - therefore not binding on the MySQL server.  Another approach would be to use Uuids for unique keys and rely on their uniqueness when you need to create a new one.

Comment: b) this is not an application logic problem. I give two inserts to mysql and curious what happens after that. I didn't ask what you answered.

Comment: @Nika - your question did state "they both have to do insert with the same vehicle_id."  Clearly  if the database defines the column as unique you can't do that so the second insert must fail.  If you want to assign unique IDs yourself (which your question does say you are doing) then your application needs to ensure they are unique.  I've explained how you can use MySQL to allow your application to do what you are trying to do.  I thought you actually had a problem that you were describing.

Comment: I was curious how locks work when inserting. looks like when there's a table and we make two inserts at the same time, one insert locks the whole table if we use index for one of the columns.

Comment: Any change to an indexed column will mean that the index has to be rebuilt. Depending on how the index is defined this may be a complex task.